# Tons of components are updating without any relevant change in state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to diagnose some intermittently awful performance in my React app, and can see lots of components updating without any change in `props` or `state`.

I've got a socket connection where whenever another user is typing, it broadcasts the fact that they're typing - this is then stored in my reducer under `typingUserData`.

Now, pretty much every component re-renders whenever this is updated, even though they never reference this variable, nor is it included in `mapStateToProps`, nor do any of their children.

I can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent updates in one component, but then every one of its children re-renders anyway. Is it intended that I should use pretty much the same `shouldComponentUpdate` on every component?

My understanding was that if I can prevent it higher up in the tree, lower components won't unnecessarily render, but they're doing that regardless. I guess I'm asking:

a) is there a way of finding out WHY they're choosing to re-render, and

b) is there a way of saying "don't render and none of your children should render either" in `shouldComponentUpdate`?

---

EDIT:
To add a little more context, I'm receiving typing data from my socket connection like so:

```
window.Echo.join('account_'+accountId).listenForWhisper('typing', e => {
    dispatch({
        type: TYPING_SET,
        payload: e,
    })
}
```

This is merged into my state like so:

```
export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TYPING_SET:
            let typingUserData = cloneDeep(state.typingUserData)

            typingUserData[action.payload.userId] = {
                isTyping: action.payload.isTyping,
                chatId: action.payload.chatId
            }

            return {
                ...state,
                typingUserData
            }
    }
}
```

SOME components listen to this from mapStateToProps like so:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    typingUserData: state.account.typingUserData,
  }
}
```

...but 99% of the components don't. For whole trees that are re-rendered, nothing in the tree references typingUserData at all.

- I'm using react-redux 5.0.7.
- As far as I can detect, nothing is mounting twice.
- Selecting 'highlight updates' in Chrome's React console tools shows pretty much everything lighting up as a result of this. Removing the action for 'typing' makes it all go away.

Hope that's enough information! Sorry for the big ol' wall of text.

Comment: My experience has involved almost never needing to define `shouldComponentUpdate`. You'll need to share some of the code involved (reducer and component portions) in order to get any advice beyond wild guesses. Even advice on finding out why they're re-rendering requires some knowledge of what your components look like.

Comment: One thing I would check is to make sure the components aren't re-mounting (add a console.log to `componentDidMount` for a couple of the components that are re-rendering). If something odd with your components is causing them to re-mount, that would defeat a lot of the optimization built into react-redux.

Comment: What specific version of React-Redux are you using? What components are being updated? Can you use the React DevTools Profiler to capture some reports, and add a screenshot of one of the updates?